# Empty Paint Method

Tags: c#, methods, initialization

I'm debugging through a new codebase and trying to figure out how things work and i came across this empty method

```
 private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

The following is within the Windows Form Designer generated code region of the InitializeComponent() method:

```
this.panel2.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.panel2_Paint);
```

I am confused as to what this method is doing, could someone possibly explain what is going on here?

Comment: Double-clicking a control in the designer automatically adds a handler for the default event for a control.  Which is Paint for the Panel control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing, more than likely they double clicked a paint event in the event window and never added any code.

Might have wanted to use it if they wanted to override or redraw controls.

Can be deleted.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but as the new guy i didn't want to rock the boat and just go and delete things without knowing completely what i'm doing.
Thanks